# Custom Block: Adding "Post Type" dropdown to Sidebar Settings

Tags: custom-post-types, block-editor, options, sidebar

I'm pretty new to React, so I'm trying to find the simplest and most PHP-based way to achieve my goal.

**What I've accomplished so far**

- Created custom blocks using the `@wordpress/create-block` package.
- The blocks can be inserted into the editor, and default block support can be added (align, etc).
- In the `render.php` I do what ever I want, the "good" old familiar PHP-way.

[image]

**The vision**

I've created a category block that displays categories of a custom post type (because the `core/categories` block only supports the default `post` post type.

At the moment I have to create multiple blocks (markup rendered in a function) for all post types that need a category list.

That works, but I would love to only create one category block and add a dropdown to the Sidebar Settings where one could choose the desired post type. Next I would dynamically pass this information to the `WP_Query` in my `render.php`.

Besides the dropdown, there ideally would also be a `text field` and a `checkbox` that I could use in the template.

**The big questions**

Is this even possible? Or is there no way around a React deep dive?

I spent hours in forums and tutorials, but couldn't find anything in that direction.

If you know about any resources or have any other hint, I'd be super grateful!